# Redshift design or configuration issue? - My Redshift datawarehouse seems much slower than my mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I have a Redshift datawarehouse that is pulling data in from multiple sources.
One is my from MySQL and the others are some cloud based databases that get pulled in.

When querying in redshift, the query response is significantly slower than the same mysql table(s).

Here is an example:
SELECT *
FROM leads
WHERE id = 10162064

In mysql this takes .4 seconds.  In Redshift it takes 4.4 seconds.

The table has 11 million rows.  "id" is indexed in mysql and in redshift it is not since it is a columnar system.

I know that Redshift is a columnar data warehouse (which is relatively new to me) and Mysql is a relational database that is able to utilize indexes.  I'm not sure if Redshift is the right tool for us for reporting, or if we need something else.  We have about 200 tables in it from 5 different systems and it is currently at 90 GB.

We have a reporting tool sitting on top that does native queries to pull data.  They are pretty slow but are also pulling a ton of data from multiple tables.  I would expect some slowness with these, but with a simple statement like above, I would expect it to be quicker.

I've tried some different DIST and SORT key configurations but see no real improvement.

I've run vacuum and analyze with no improvement.

We have 4 nodes, dc2.large.  Currently only using 14% storage.  CPU utilization is frequently near 100%.  Database connections averages about 10 at any given time.

The datawarehouse just has exact copies of the tables from our integration with the other sources. We are trying to do near real-time reporting with this.

Just looking for advice on how to improve performance of our redshift via configuration changes, some sort of view or dim table architecture, or any other tips to help me get the most out of redshift.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with clients on this type of issue many times and I'm happy to help but this may take some back and forth to narrow in on what is happening.

First I'm assuming that "leads" is a normal table, not a view and not an external table.  Please correct if this assumption isn't right.

Next I'm assuming that this table isn't very wide and that "select *" isn't contributing greatly to the speed concern.  Yes?

Next question is wide this size of cluster for a table of only 11M rows?  I'd guess it is that there are other much larger data sets on the database and that this table isn't setting the size.

The first step of narrowing this down is to go onto the AWS console for Redshift and find the query in question.  Look at the actual execution statistics and see where the query is spending its time.  I'd guess it will be in loading (scanning) the table but you never know.

You also should look at STL_WLM_QUERY for the query in question and see how much wait time there was with the running of this query.  Queueing can take time and if you have interactive queries that need faster response times then some WLM configuration may be needed.

It could also be compile time but given the simplicity of the query this seems unlikely.

My suspicion is that the table is spread too thin around the cluster and there are lots of mostly empty blocks being read but this is just based on assumptions.  Is "id" the distkey or sortkey for this table?  Other factors likely in play are cluster load - is the cluster busy when this query runs?  WLM is one place that things can interfere but disk IO bandwidth is a share resource and if some other queries are abusing the disks this will make every query's access to disk slow.  (Same is true of network bandwidth and leader node workload but these don't seem to be central to your issue at the moment.)

As I mentioned resolving this will likely take some back and forth so leave comments if you have additional information.

Comment: Yes, leads is a normal table with about 20 columns.  I went to 4 clusters from 2 because we have about 200 different tables.  Some of them have many more rows and one table in particular has about 450 columns. Crazy, I know.

So I have looked at the query performance in redshift console, and it doesn't offer much help for me.  I have this issue with basically all queries I run.  This is just a simple example of one.  Many of my queries are very long with multiple joins  of 5+ tables.  I do break out by CTE and temp table when possible, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Comment: Did the console report that the "scan" phase was most of the time?  What about queue wait time?  If every query is taking 4+ sec to run I'm wondering about something more systemic.  Large latencies between your client and Redshift Or high cluster load / queue wait times.  Does any of this ring true?  What is your WLM configuration and you likely concurrent query load?

Comment: XN Seq Scan on leads (cost=0.00..0.001 rows=1, width = 319).  Total_Queue_Time = 0.

To be honest, WLM Configuration has never been adjusted, so whatever the auto setting is.  I'm still trying to figure this part out.

I have about 10 queries running at any point including integration loading the tables and report refreshes.

Comment: As I'm reading into WLM, I see there might be a clear issue.  I am using the same user for for INSERTS/UPDATES as SELECTS.  I'll dig deeper and will look for any updates from you.  Thanks.

Comment: A few things:  This performance report looks to be the EXPLAIN plan (expected performance).  The console also has actual performance with step execution times in msecs.  If you have the default parameter group then yes you have auto-WLM which should have enough slots for 10 concurrent queries.  One feature to think about enabling is "short query acceleration" (SQA) which will push small queries like this to the front of the queue.

Comment: If you have you short queries and longer queries in the same queue then, yes, this can lead to delays in starting the short queries.  SQA that I mentioned above can help with this but you may want to have separate queues for these query classes.  You can also give the "dashboard" query queue a higher priority in the auto-WLM config to ensure these move quicker.  Looking at STL_WLM_QUERY to see if the queries you are concerned about are waiting in the queue for a slot will help confirm that we are on the right path.

Comment: OK, so in the console it says just 1 step which is just Seq Scan on leads.  It also says very selective query filter and review choice of sort key or run the vacuum.  The problem with sort key on this table is that today I'm searching by "id" field, but other queries look at other fields and not all the same fields.  My understanding is that sort keys are difficult in this way.

Regarding STL_WLM_QUERY, it doesn't look like total_queue_time is a problem.  Just looking at the last 30 minutes, my hardest hitting queries have a total queue time of 0 while individual exec_time of 39,228,705

Comment: 1 step makes sense.  Is the time to execute this step approximately the time of the query?  Based on what we have discussed I think it should be.  I wouldn't expect sort keys to do much for you with a table this size - it's just too small for the cluster.  11M rows split between 8 slices means that each slice has about 1.5M rows which I would expect to be about 3-4 blocks (1MB chunk).  The range of values in any block is unlikely to give you much selectivity.  This is why super-sizing Redshift doesn't always give you a benefit.

Comment: Back to the table scan (the current prime target) - I'd expect that the actual execution stats would show that all 11M rows were scanned.  The MBs scanned is likely around 100MB - this assumes that there aren't any super-sized columns and that compression is enabled.  Any of this look way different?

Comment: So I just ran the same query with a different id.  Total runtime 151ms.  6 rows scanned, 1.4KB.  Seems to be faster.

Comment: It is good to have a "good" and "bad" example to track down differences but let's confirm that this improvement is not due to result caching.  Have you turned off caching with "SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF;"?  If caching is removed from results then can you explore what is the important difference between the "good" and the "bad" query - is it the id used? or the time when it ran?

Comment: I just turned caching off and the query still ran in 600 ms now.  Seems like a big difference from 4.4 seconds the other day and I didn't make any changes.  So could possibly be a time of day issue...

Comment: That would be my #1 guess.  Really a 'what else is going on' issue.  Given what your query is doing and that there wasn't a long queue wait time for this query when it took 4 sec, I'd look at congestion in the disk access at that time.  Unfortunately this implies that the issue is with other queries.  Look at STL_SCAN for the time window when your query took 4 sec and see if there are any/many queries with large data sizes.  There are other places that thing could be congested but this seems like the most likely.

Comment: Just to document other "shared" areas in Redshift that can cause a query to be slow due to other activity on the cluster.  These include: disk access (both reading and writing), network bandwidth, leader node (return data, compiling), and queue slots.  Given the nature of the query you are running excessive disk usage is the mostly likely area where other queries could be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

(I am speaking from a knowledge of MySQL, not Redshift.)

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE id = 10162064
```

If `id` is indexed, especially if it is a Unique (or Primary) key, 0.4 sec sounds like a long network delay.  I would expect 0.004 as a worst-case (with SSDs and `PRIMARY KEY(id)).

(If `leads` is a `VIEW`, then let's see the tables.  0.4s may be be reasonable!)

That query works well for a RDBMS, but *not* for a columnar database.  Face it.

I can understand using a columnar database to handle random queries on various columns.  See also MariaDB's implementation of "Columnstore" -- that would give you both RDBMS and Columnar in a single package.  Still, they are separate enough that you can't really intermix the two technologies.

If you are getting 100% CPU in MySQL, show us the query, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Often, a better index and/or query formulation can solve that.

For "real time reporting" in a Data Warehouse, building and maintaining [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) is often the answer.

Tell us more about the "exact copy" of the DW data.  In some situations, the Summary tables can supplant one copy of the Fact table data.